# Drupal 7 use teaser as a block

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, teaser

Can the teaser on the front page to be used as a customized block element, and to be assigned in any other regions and to be shown on every pages?

Or is there any module for this function in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module to create a block with node titles and teasers similar to the default front page.